# Set the value of a formula field by coping the value of field within the object but only to a specific record type

Tags: formula

We have contact object with two record type. One is A and the other one B. We have field called last name and prefeered name on A record type. We dont use the preferred name on B record type.

I am thinking to create a formula field, that copies the value of last name and puts it into preferred name field. But only do that to A record type. If its a B record type leave it as Null or Blank.Is it possible to do via formula or do i have to create a flow to do it?

This way when users run a report without seeing the field populated on all record types.

Please let me know if its possible.

Regards
Kamala

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use simple if condition in your formula to achieve your solution:-

```
 IF( RecordType.DeveloperName == 'ABC', LastName , '')
```

Comment: Hi Sanket, thank you for your response. But when i used the formula it copies the last name as the value rather than the actual last name of the record. And for some reason it is also copying to all record types. Example the last name is Kamala and the value it copied was last name. Not sure what i was doing wrong.

Comment: Can you update the formula you have used in your question?